# Apache ActiveMQ Artemis reports incorrect Memory Usage?

Tags: activemq-artemis

I was troubleshooting an issue with ActiveMQ Artemis 2.28.0, and I came to the conclusion that the memory usage that is being reported and is used by Artemis to decide when to offload messages to disk is incorrect. I know it's a hard statement so hope I'm misunderstanding something.

Was able to reproduce it in multiple environments. For example, on my local machine running Artemis with the following configurations:

- **JVM Settings:** -Xms512M -Xmx2G
- **Global Max Size:** Using default (The system will use half of the available memory (-Xmx) by default for the global-max-size)

I expect the system will enter into page mode once I hit the 1G limit right (i.e. half of -Xmx2G).

However, Artemis starts acting weird even before it gets to the 1G limit. In my simulation it happened when Artemis was reporting 499MB usage. I got this number from both Artemis Console and CLI ( bin/artemis check node --memoryUsage 50).

"Acting weird" definition is a bit different in PROD and of what I was able to reproduce on my local, but it starts when the broker's JVM is getting close to it's Xmx limit.

In production consumer will silently stop consuming messages, and producers will hang sending messages. My local consumer will throw an Exception like this and then disconnect:

```
Execution of JMS message listener failed, and no ErrorHandler has been set. javax.jms.JMSException: Cannot send, channel has already failed: tcp://172.18.0.6:61616
```

In both cases Artemis logs show no errors or signs of misbehavior.

**Grounds for my conclusion:**
I checked the actual usage, and it seems like the Java process for Artemis is using 1.8G RAM.

Have anyone other than me noticed this behavior? Am I missing anything?

Comment: Can you provide the code you're using to test this?

Comment: Have you gathered and analyzed any heap dumps to see what is consuming the memory? If so, what was the result of your analysis?

Comment: I'm using Apache ActiveMQ Artemis 2.28.0! "Acting weird" definition is a bit different in PROD and of what I was able to reproduce on my local, but it starts when AMQ is getting close to it's Xmx limit.

Comment: In production consumer will silently stop consuming messages, and producers will hang sending messages. 
On my local consumer will throw an Exception like this:
"Execution of JMS message listener failed, and no ErrorHandler has been set.
javax.jms.JMSException: Cannot send, channel has already failed: tcp://172.18.0.6:61616", and then disconnect. In both cases Artemis logs show no errors or signs of misbehavior.

Comment: Code will be a bit challenging since I was running tests using our application, perhaps my next step would be to try exposing a reproducible testcase.

Comment: Every JVM will start acting a bit different than normal as it gets close to its Xmx due to extra effort from the garbage collector. This may lead to connection timeouts and other problems as the CPU is spending longer and longer amounts of time trying to free up memory. It would be worthwhile to acquire and analyze heap dumps from the broker along the way to see what's consuming the memory. It would also be worth getting thread dumps from the producers that are hanging to see exactly _where_ they are hanging. Ultimately you may simply want to set a lower `global-max-size` than the default.

Comment: What kind of clients are you using?

Comment: Thanks! Probably setting lower global-max-size is what we will end up doing...  do you know if there is a way to set it as a percentile of allocated heap?

Comment: @JustinBertram we are running an application that uses Spring and Spring Integration. Using org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledConnectionFactory to connect to the Broker.

Comment: You can only explicitly set `global-max-size` as a specific value, not as a percentage of heap.

Comment: Given that you're using `org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledConnectionFactory` does that mean you're using the OpenWire JMS client that ships with ActiveMQ "Classic"?

Comment: Yes, OpenWire JMS client that ships with ActiveMQ "Classic". We are trying to migrate our applications to Artemis from ActiveMQ "Classic"... the phase one was supposed to simply switch to Artemis and keep using JMS2 compliant clients (That are using OpenWire protocol)... as part of phase2 we were planning to start migrating applications one by one to JMS3 compliant Artemis client.

Comment: We ended up rolling back to ActiveMQ "Classic" yesterday since the stalled connections were happening even when Broker was not running high on memory :-(  So now, with reduced pressure I really want to understand what is going on! Thanks for all your replies Justin, they are really helpful! I'm going to open another topic describing the behavior. Would greatly appreciate any troubleshooting suggestions that you can think of!